# If 10 is not a solitary number, what properties would a friend of 10 have

Tags: number-theory

It is of course an unsolved problem if 10 is solitary or not, but it is conjectured that it is.
(See definition of friendly and solitary number on wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_number)

So why is it conjectured that 10 is solitary? Wikipedia says that if 10 has a friend it is "a fairly large number". Presumably a computer search found no example.
But pairs can be friends, even if they live quite far appart. An example is (24,91963648). Solely on that grounds I wouldn't conjecture it if there aren't any more reasons.

I found out that a possible friend of 10 is divisible by 5 and is not divisible by 2. But that's as far as I got. Are there any other known restrictions that point to the conjecture?

Comment: I think you meant "is divisble by" in your last sentence, there aren't many numbers dividing 5!

Comment: Ah yes, you are right of course :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is more information in the paper 'Does ten have a friend' by Jeffrey Ward.  It is available at http://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.1001v2.pdf  (see theorem 1 in that paper).

Comment: Ah that's exactly what I was looking for. It does narrow the possibilities down quite heavily.